# Typing in a number higher than the LEQ boundaries crashes my batch file

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a program in batch that responds with the corresponding letter of the number you type in. 1=A, 2=B, 3=C, and so on. I made an if statement that echos something if you type in a number lower than 1, but I can't figure out how to get it to echo something when I type a number higher that 26. I've tried adding many different "else if _____ GEQ ___" statements, but none of them worked. Any help would be appreciated.

My code might be a little messy, sorry.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:realstart
cls
set alph[0]=a
set alph[1]=b
set alph[2]=c   
set alph[3]=d   
set alph[4]=e
set alph[5]=f
set alph[6]=g
set alph[7]=h
set alph[8]=i
set alph[9]=j
set alph[10]=k
set alph[11]=l
set alph[12]=m
set alph[13]=n
set alph[14]=o
set alph[15]=p
set alph[16]=q
set alph[17]=r
set alph[18]=s
set alph[19]=t
set alph[20]=u
set alph[21]=v
set alph[22]=w
set alph[23]=x
set alph[24]=y
set alph[25]=z
set len=0
set input=0

:start
IF "!len!"=="26" (
    goto respond
) ELSE (
    set /a len+=1
    call echo       %%alph[%len%]%%
    goto start
)


:respond
echo.
echo.
set /p input=Enter a number: 
set /a input-=1

IF %input% LSS 0 (
    echo u suck
    ping localhost -n 2 >nul
    goto realstart
) ELSE IF %input% LEQ 25 (
    set letter=!alph[%input%]!
    echo.
    echo !letter!
    ping localhost -n 2 >nul
    goto realstart
)
pause >nul
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question... you need to accommodate the condition of the number being too large by doing something with that condition. Replace the line

```
pause >nul
```

with something like this:

```
echo The number you entered is too large
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
goto realstart
```

Comment: This worked really well. I didn't think that the answer would be so simple. Thinking about it now, this makes a lot of sense. Having it at the end I guess is just the final thing it goes too if either of the other conditions don't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly an answer to your posed question. It's more a different methodology to achieving your goal:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:RealStart
ClS
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('Set alph[ 2^>NUL') Do Set "%%G="
Set "input=0"
For %%G In (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) Do (
    Set "alph[!input!]=%%G"&Set /A input+=1)

:Start
For /L %%G In (0 1 25) Do Set /P "input=!alph[%%G]! "<NUL

:Respond
Echo(
Echo(
Set "input="
Set /P "input=Enter a number in the range 1..26: "
Set input 2>NUL|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /X "input=[123456789] input=1[0123456789] input=2[0123456]">NUL||(
    Echo U suck
    %__AppDir__%timeout.exe 1 /NoBreak>NUL
    GoTo Respond)
Set /A input-=1
Set "letter=!alph[%input%]!"
Set "input="
Echo(
Echo %letter%
%__AppDir__%timeout.exe -1
GoTo :EOF
```

I hope it helps you out!